# cast text to xml error illegal qualified name character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how to fix error illegal qualified name character in this sample :

```
 Declare @Str As nvarchar(256)
 Set @Str = N'<Log "ReceiptStockHNo="2" ReceiptStockHDate="Feb  4 2" Comment="" />'
 Select Cast(@Str As xml)
```

Error :

> Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 6, illegal qualified name character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is this  extra `"` ? .

[image]

Remove the `"` and it will work.

Additional information :

To prevent future errors for needed encoded characters like `&` , `<` , use  the appropriate replacement :

```
 Declare @Str As nvarchar(256)
 Set @Str =  '<tag>&</tag>'
 Select Cast(@Str As xml)
```

Will yield :

> Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 XML parsing: line 1, character 7
>   illegal name character

While changing `<` to `&lt;` :

```
 Declare @Str As nvarchar(256)
 Set @Str =  '<tag>&lt;</tag>'
 Select Cast(@Str As xml)
```

Will be Ok.

Comment: ,thanks for answer ,how to remove  "   character with t-sql ?

Comment: @Iraj I believe it's a new question so ask it as a new question. ( but serach before asking) :-)